# Nodejs service stops automatically

Tags: php, node.js, sockets

we are working on project where we have used node-js in background socket for continues respond to web application. In between sometimes somehow some process stops automatically.

We would like to know how we can check all the process running using forever.

We are using sudo forever list to list all process. Is there any way to use this command(forever list) in .sh(shell script file) to check my specific process like responsclient is working or not. If that particular process is not working then we needs to start that.

Answer (score 1):

There are several solutions that will ensure that your service is always running.

One of them is even called `forever`. Here you have an overview prepared by [express](https://expressjs.com/en/advanced/pm.html).

However, for production services I recommend [passenger](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/) The result is almost the same, but much greater scalability. For example, you can configure so that another instance is automatically added.

Almost - because it is designed to ensure the availability of HTTP, and not the constant operation of the application.

BTW: service stops, because you have uncatched exception.

#### Update

If you insist on `forever`, then: (We're talking about the same [forever](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever#command-line-usage)?)

- Make sure that `forever` is run by the same user. `forever` has separate managers for all users.
- Make sure you save your data in the same place. (automatic run eg by `cron` is different from manual startup (vaiables in `env`))
- `forever` has `--pidFile` - then it is very easy to check if the process is working
- also `ps -aux | grep node` should be your big friend.

No, I do not have it combined. When I started to have problems, I switched to `passenger`. Finally I did it well because I have professional monitoring, which I launched in less time than searching how to combine the above points together.

Comment: forever is a service of ubuntu while i would like to iterate loop to check all process of forever. As one my my service is started using forever that automatically stops.

Comment: sorry, my poor english... `forever list` works for user who run forever instance

Comment: I used 'forever' once. It seemed great for my needs. But over time, needs began to grow and now I use `passenger` even for small things.

Comment: I think  you are not getting my point, we would like to setup a schedular in which we would like to check all process of forever is working or not. if any of our required process is not working then restart that process.

Comment: And you do not understand mine. Your choice, but to re-discover the wheel you need to have a lot of knowledge. (see update)

Comment: btw: https://www.exratione.com/2013/02/nodejs-and-forever-as-a-service-simple-upstart-and-init-scripts-for-ubuntu/